# Redirect to new URL and keep path Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to redirect to another URL but keep trailing path.

I use `window.location.href;` to redirect to another URL, but how do I keep path. What I want is illustrated below.

**ORIGINAL URL**

```
<script>
window.location.href="www.example.com/the_path";
</script>
```

to be redirected too

```
<script>
window.location.href="mobile.example.com/the_path";
</script>
```

I want to the keep "the_path", I need that part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL constructor to create a new url using the current location.href then simply change the host

```js
// create a path in this demo only
history.pushState(null,null, '/the_path?foo=bar')


const url = new URL(location.href)
url.hostname = 'mobile.example.com';


console.log(url.href)
```

Comment: Did this not help you solve your issue?